# Query a database inside a running container

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I have a java program that queries a database inside a container. Now if I use the ip it works well, the localhost or docker0 interface, but I want to port the app inside kubernetes, and there I want to use the name of the container, so the connection string now is that:

```
    public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://dbContainer:3306/schema1?useSSL=false";
```

and the container with the db inside is call dbContainer

But I get an error in the terminal:

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dbContainer: Nome o servizio sconosciuto
>   at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
>   at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)

How could I refer to it with the containername?

Comment: You probably want to talk about [tag:docker] instead of [tag:dock]. Please confirm

Answer (score 0):

The java file is inside one other containet and the host

Comment: the file is inside one other container of java

Answer (score 0):

I have solver that using link, with link i ad a reference to it with a name